# Unable to print hollow diamond pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, design-patterns

*Beginner to Programming*

My code is below , the spaces within diamond is shown with 'B' and spaces outside diamond are shown with X.

```
n=5
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(n,i,-1):
    if j==i+1:
      print('*',end='')
      break
    print('X',end='')
  for j in range(i):
    print('B',end='')
  for j in range(i+1):
    if i==0:
      continue
    if j==i-1:
      print('*',end='')
      break
    print('B',end='')
  print('')
#Downward
for i in range(n-1):
  for j in range(i+2):
    if j==i+1:
      print('*',end='')
      break
    print('X',end='')
  for j in range(n-1,i+2,-1):
    print('B',end='')
  for j in range(n-1,i,-1):
    if i==n-2:
        break
    if j==i+1:
      print('*')
      break
    print('B',end='')
  print('')
```

Result:

```
XXXX*
XXX*B*
XX*BBB*
X*BBBBB*
*BBBBBBB*
X*BBBBB*

XX*BBB*

XXX*B*

XXXX*
```

Despite equal number of 'B' and 'X' , i don't know which part of code is introducing a space between lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it to print Diamond shape of the desired height.

```
row = int(input('Enter number of row: '))

# Upper part of hollow diamond
for i in range(1, row+1):
    for j in range(1,row-i+1):
        print(" ", end="")
    for j in range(1, 2*i):
        if j==1 or j==2*i-1:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()

# Lower part of hollow diamond
for i in range(row-1,0, -1):
    for j in range(1,row-i+1):
        print(" ", end="")
    for j in range(1, 2*i):
        if j==1 or j==2*i-1:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but I'm still confused why my code is producing extra space on the lower hollow traingle. I tried pythontutor.com but still don't know what's producing extra space when new row starts in the lower triangle.

Answer (score 0):

So I found it,

```
  for j in range(n-1,i,-1):
    if i==n-2:
        break
    if j==i+1:
      print('*', end='') # <---This line had the problem
      break
    print('B',end='')
```